# Can I save into a specific folder?

Tags: file-io, lua, directory, love2d, platform-specific

While learning how to create Lua file output code with the support of LÖVE, I've always hated that LÖVE filesystem handler always saved the specific file somewhere in C:/Documents and Settings/...

How can I create a code that saves a file into a specific folder that I'd like to define (and maybe to change while running the application)?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The love.filesystem library doesn't let you do anything outside the sandbox. However, LÖVE doesn't disable Lua's built in `io` library, so you can use `io.open` to open files outside the sandbox and read/write them as normal, as well as other Lua functions like `require` and `loadfile`.

It also doesn't restrict loading of external modules, so you can (for example) `require "lfs"` to load LuaFileSystem and use that, if it is installed.

Comment: I don't want to install lfs, but anyway, thanks for answering!

Comment: You don't need to install lfs for basic file io, just use the `io` library. If you want to do something like list directory contents, though, you'll need it.